# Windows 10 quality updates deferral setting

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I use Windows 10 x64 Pro 1909 and have quality updates deferred for 15 days (feature updates deferred for 120 days).

As of today (June 21, 2020) the latest cumulative update I have installed is 2020-05 (KB4556799)

2020-06 update (KB4560960) was released on June 9. It is now known that it breaks printing in some configurations.

Question 1: will KB4560960 still be pushed to my PC 15 days after release date even though there is a known issue?

Question 2: let's say fix for printing is already released by Microsoft (I don't know if this is actually the case). When will I receive this fix as automatic update? Will it also be received with 15 day delay, just like everything else? Or does Microsoft push such updates with no delay as "emergency fix"?

Comment: Microsoft is issuing updates to existing systems to correct for this issue and will not offer V2004 to such machines until fixes have been applied. Do not force the update. Wait for your machine to update on its own.

Comment: The printing issue has already been resolved but requires installing the appropriate optional patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: will KB4560960 still be pushed to my PC 15 days after release date even though there is a known issue?

Microsoft has not pulled KB4560960 so it absolutely will eventually be installed on your system.  The printer issue has already been resolved but you must install an optional patch if you encounter the issue.

> let's say fix for printing is already released by Microsoft (I don't know if this is actually the case). When will I receive this fix as automatic update?

The optional patch that resolves the printer spool is not being distributed by Windows Update as of today.  Microsoft will eventually will incorporate that fix in a future cumulative update that will be distributed.

[KB4567512](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4567512)

> Will it also be received with 15 day delay, just like everything else?

Yes; The future cumulative update will respect your 15 day deferment setting.

> Or does Microsoft push such updates with no delay as "emergency fix"?

The printer spool optional patch doesn’t reach the level of severity to raise the level of an emergency patch.

Answer (score 1):

I have quality updates deferred for three days on my work laptop and KB4560960 was installed.

There is a fix for the printer problem but it is not being installed through Windows Update. You have to get it from the update catalog.

[KB4567512](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4567512)